# Put a gap in between two views in Swift Alert

Tags: swift, uialertview

I created Alert View with two text field for user to enter details. Alert View is generated programmatically as shown below. Is there is any way to put a gap in between two text field?.

```
 let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Register", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)

alertController.addAction(OKAction)

alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) in
    textField.placeholder = "Name"
    textField.keyboardType = .EmailAddress
}

alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) in
    textField.placeholder = "Email"
    textField.secureTextEntry = false
}

alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) in
    textField.placeholder = "Company"
    textField.secureTextEntry = false
}


        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
            // ...
        }
```

[Here the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyRER.png)

Comment: Why not using a Modal View Controller to do that? Much easier.

Comment: Could you explain .?

Comment: You're trying to create a form in a alert view. Alert view are good for confirmations, create a view controller for that and present it modally. You're got to get a lot more flexibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you a better way.
Create a custom xib file and use present view controller to create an alert box as shown below.

```
 let vc = CustomAlertViewController()
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You can refer following repo
https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7